# Get the "Most Visited" links / pages in a site

Tags: jquery, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I got few tables storing some information. Users are allow to click on the title of the information and then view the details.

I want to retrieve and display a list of "Most Popular" (links with the most hits) links in the homepage, but I never come across things like this so I wonder how can I do that.

Note: I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with database ADO.NET + Entity Model

If possible, I prefer solution using jquery or maybe LINQ. Hope can get some advices here... Thanks!

Comment: Are you tracking page visits in the database?

Comment: you're gonna need to gather and store traffic information in your database, then use that to display your Most Popular links.

Comment: Have a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349842/user-tracking-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-views. The part: `//save url, userId from session, etc...` is where you'd increment a value in a table for the URL.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by "traffic information"? Is it I need to add a row in each table, and increment the count everytime user click on the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no one providing a "proper" way to do this.

I will use an additional to store the count and increment it everytime the View is displayed. Thanks!